# Pycharm unresolved reference in virtualenv

Tags: python, django, pycharm

When I started a new project in Pycharm using virtual environment, I got an unresolved reference warning message.

[image]

But I have installed django to my virtual environment and this code is working  correctly.

How can I fix this? I'm using PyCharm 4.5.2 Pro

Comment: Have you setup your specific project interpreter to point to your virtual env under preferences?

Comment: Yes. Pycharm automatically set it when I create project

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: Yes  and  it doesn't help

Comment: I'm having exactly this problem. Created new project, used PyCharm to create new virtualenv, and the first file I write can't find builtins like "math" and "collections". Configuration seems to be the same as all my working projects, turned on/off, invalidated caches, flagged directory as source... problem persists.

Comment: u can create virtual environment in pycharm even and install necessary libraries so that it shows u recommendations. As you create virtual environment for ur django server to run, u can create virtual environment in pycharm also

Answer (score 11):

Open your project in pycharm and follow the step:

click on file(on top) > settings > project interpreter > add local > select virtualenv

```
                      OR
```

Make sure your project is a root directory, make it is the root directory.

Answer (score 5):

I eventually stumbled across a method that worked for me, but I don't know the underlying problem.

Initially I created a virtualenv with PyCharm in the interpreter options. Annoyed that I was having this problem, I deleted it and just created a virtualenv with the virtualenv command, but the problem remained.

Then I went back to the interpreter selector and picked "add local". I navigated to the python binary in the /bin folder of the virtualenv I created and selected it. After this, the unresolved references were fixed.

Comment: yup. That was the problem for me as well. Seems you have to select both the virtualenv and what python binary to use. Otherwise the auto completion module will not work for the packages in the virtualenv.

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem is like mine. I tested `import matplotlib` in the python shell, and it works, but in Pycharm it shows an error. This is because Pycharm doesn't know the path of site-packages.

To fix this, you can do one of the following:

- Add the path of site-packages (for me C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages) to PATH.
- Go to File -> Settings -> Project Interpreter, then choose *Python real path* instead of *venu path*.
  [image]
- In your code add the following:

.

```
import sys    
sys.path.append(r"C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I think it will help you :)

Comment: Thank you so much @Artemis Fowl for edit suggestion. Thank  you so much!

Comment: This works for me in 2022

Answer (score 2):

[image: File > Settings > Project > Project Structure]

File > Settings > Project > Project Structure
Double Click on the folder link under Content Root, and do OK.

Answer (score 0):

Check your project root directory. Maybe problem in it.

And did you create virtualenv manually or through PyCharm?

Comment: I create virtualenv through PyCharm, root directory is correct